# Issues populating AVAssetTrack with AVURLAsset

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avasset

I am currently working on an iPhone app that takes short snippets of video and compiles them together in a AVMutableComposition that is then exported to the user's camera roll.  The example code I am using prompts the user to select the video to be merged from their camera roll and works flawlessly.  The issue I am running into has to do with the fact that in the production app I am passing the videos to be compiled in the form of an array or their URL's.  I am able to successfully populate the AVURLAsset with the following code:

```
newUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempURLholder];
Asset0 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:newUrl options:nil];
```

However when I attempt to then pass that AVURLAsset onto the AVMutableCompositionTrack I get a null value with this code:

```
track0 = [mainComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[track0 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, Asset0.duration) ofTrack:[[Asset0 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

And when I attempt to just pass the raw asset I get a 'incompatible pointer sending AVURLAsset to AVAssetTrack' error with this code:

```
track0 = [mainComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[track0 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, Asset0.duration) ofTrack:Asset0 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

I know I am probably missing something really simple here has anyone has experience with this or would be willing to pass along some tips to get my resources to show? Thanks so much in advance.